# Mapbox toggle layers > double click required to hide layer?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I have followed the mapbox toggle layers demo (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/) on my map project.

In order to turn a layer 'off', I need to click twice on the actual button - once to select, and then a second time to actually hide the layer.

The demo map only requires a single click to show/hide layers.

How can I fix this?

My map is at: https://qlddogs.com.au/maptest2.html

Comment: I think it has to do with your use of `stopPropogation()` but I can't be sure. If you can set up a minimal jsfiddle or jsbin I can look more closely.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this: 

https://jsfiddle.net/2w4ob9ja/